# How to send a parameter from an object to another angular component through a method?

Tags: angular

was passing an object id to component.ts, but it arrives as null.

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row (click)="detalhes(veiculo?.id!)" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

I want when passing this veiculo.id to the detalhe(id: number) method, the user will be sent to the link details/id.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'veiculo' },
  { path: 'veiculo', component: VeiculoComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'cadastro', component: CadastroVeiculosComponent },
  { path: 'detalhes/:id', component: VeiculoDetalhesComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];
```

This is the method that is in component.ts

```
detalhes(id: number) {
    console.log(id);
    return this.router.navigateByUrl('detalhes' + `${id}`);
}
```

What should I do to pass this id, or any other parameters, to Component.ts?

Sorry for code in portuguese.

Comment: What is the purpose of exclamation mark on `(click)="detalhes(veiculo?.id!)"`, is it a typo?

Comment: @MaxTuzenko Why was this error   `Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. To remove error you just mentioned, if I understand it correctly, you should prevent function "detalhes" from executing without params. First mark param as optional, then add line preventing execution if there is no id: `detalhes(id?:number){ if ( !id ) return;}`

Answer (score 0):

you can pass it to url in this way:

```js
detalhes(id: number) {
    console.log(id);
    return this.router.navigateByUrl(`detalhes/${id}`);
}
```

and then in your component you can access to url by the ActivatedRoute:

```js
//yourComponent.component.ts

id!:number;

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {};

ngOnInit() {
 // subscribe to router event
  this.id= this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id")
}
```

[here](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) you can read about the activatedRoute service

Comment: Correct. But, even better to add a resolver to the route and subscribe to the route's data observable within the component.

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: check: https://pieter-hogent.github.io/web4/7_routing.html